# 1 Working Day Back In SQL DB2

Tags: sql, vba, db2

I need to select data from database with a date that is one day back into the past but on working day. Is there a specific function for that ( Excel has got formula =Workday)?

I am downloading data from DB2 to excel with VBA instructions.

Here is the piece of code I use for calendar day.

```html
strSQL = "SELECT *"
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM PDB2I.DI_HIS_EXH_RAT_01"
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE CAR_DT = CURRENT DATE - 1 DAY"
```

Thanks in advance for any directions

Comment: How do you define a "working day"? Do you need to account for holidays?

Comment: working days are defined as from Monday til Friday

Comment: In that case the solution offered below should work (after being rewritten to DB2 SQL, taking into account the DB2 version and platform you work with).

Comment: Would you please be able to rewrite it into Db2?

Comment: Not without the necessary details.

Comment: Tell me what details you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * 
from mytable 
where mydate = current date - 
    (case when dayofweek(current date) = 1 then 2 -- sonntag
          when dayofweek(current date) = 2 then 3 -- montag
          else 1 end) days
```

Comment: It works thank you very much. I only had to remove the notes inside the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check what day of the week it is and change accordingly

```
select * from table_x where timestamp_x > (select PREV_WEEKDAY from(select sysdate as current_date,
       case when to_char(sysdate,'D') in (1,2,7)
            then next_day(sysdate-7,'Friday')
            else sysdate-1 end as prev_weekday
from dual))
```

Comment: the problem is that people that are supposed to use it are not able to do any manipulations with code like this The need is for the code to always calculate one working day back without human intervention

Comment: @Tommeck37 I don't understand what the problem is. I changed the example i provided in hopes that it is more applicable now. It can be simplified but I left it fairly verbose so it's easier to understand

Comment: I must have written post at the same time as you were amending it. Thank you Brian. Now it seems more applicable for me. I will keep you posted once I've tried it at work

Comment: That's not really DB2 SQL, is it?

Comment: Yes it seems to me it is not Db2 as query does not work